# meteor bindenvironnement issue

Tags: meteor, meteorite

```
getTime: function () {
                             host="http://www.xxxxxx.com/";
                       res= Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(){
                            var Fiber = Meteor.require('fibers');
                            var Future = Meteor.require('fibers/future');
                            var future = new Future();
                           request(host, function (error, response, body) {
                            Fiber(function(){
                                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

                                    $ = cheerio.load(body);

                                    var $thumbs = $('.thumb');

                                    for (var i = 0, l = $thumbs.length ; i < l ; i++) {

                                        // elements
                                        var $thumb = $($thumbs[i]);
                                        // save info
                                        videourl=host+$thumb.find('a').attr('href');
                                        videothumbs = [$thumb.find('img').attr('src')];

                                        videos=Videos.insert({title:videoTitle,thumbs:videothumbs,lastUpdated:Date.now()});

                                    }

                                   return videos;
                                }
                                else {
                                    return "error";
                                }
                            }).run()
                        });
                   }) ;
                   return res;
                }
```

This is a server side method and returning `undefined`

Without bindenvironment it is returning error to use bindenvironemnt.

Am I using it properly, can somebody tell m the modifications in my code

Comment: You're supposed to call the wrapped function somewhere, so you probably need `res()`. Also, what exact error are you getting and where exactly you're using this `getTime` function?

Comment: Using Meteor HTTP.get sync version (http://docs.meteor.com/#http_call) instead of npm request you wouldn't need all the Fiber stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need a future to return the value of inner function:

```
Meteor.methods({
  getTime: function() {
    var future = new Future();
    Meteor.bindEnvironment(function() {
      future.return('Some value');
    });

    return future.wait();
  },
});
```

Check out [this Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/SCsmnRhsPcL9tNmu2) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use suggestion from **@saimeunt** comment, then your code could be simplified into form:

SERVER:

```
Meteor.methods({
  getSite:function(url){
    var site = HTTP.get(url);
    console.log("statusCode =\n " , site.statusCode);
    console.log("content.length =\n ",site.content.length);
    console.log("header =\n ",site.headers);
    $ = cheerio.load(content);
    ...
  }
})
```

CLIENT :

```
Meteor.call("getSite", "http://www.google.com");
```

[See how it works](http://meteorpad.com/pad/fJJWHjih8wMBS3fAr)